# how to set monthly bandwidth usage on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I have a web server that run on FreeBSD 10.2 and sysutils/iocage.
Every domain has its own jail..
To serve all the domain jails, I have a web reverse proxy jail.
My question is:
How can I set the monthly bandwidth usage of let say 4GB/month and then possibly throttle the IP/jail once the limit is reached when we haven't got a cpanel installed?

What tools do you guys use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple tools, probably [vnstat](https://www.freshports.org/net/vnstat/) can help with the bandwidth.

Regarding throttling/[limiting](http://microsux.dk/?p=321) the network, maybe [PF ALTQ](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-pf.html) could help.

For limits like CPU/MEMORY [rctl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rctl&sektion=8) does a good job